# jquery trigger action on option add

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an select field which is on a jsp page and I add options to it through an external js library. Now is there a way on my jsp to trigger an action when an option is added?

Its because I need to get some value from backend and its not possible to do everything on an external js page.

I used .change() but I guess because of the fact that the adding takes place in an external page, it does not trigger anything.

Comment: Please paste some code here for us to understand better ..!! you can edit that external JS to call your JS while performing onchange() event. You can make an AJAX call on onchange() and get the values from DB. However if we can see some code here, we may come up with some solutions

Comment: Calling a function from  my external js could be the solution, thanks man, I ll update the comment once I test

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on`

```
$('#your_dropdown_id').on('change', function (d) {
 // your code here..
});
```

Comment: didnt help, I guess this does the same thing as change

Comment: Its difficult to suggest anything without code, but where in code you add items to your list and where do you call the .change function ?